# Podfile error while doing "pod install"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I made my own cocoa pods using this tutorial.
http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html
I pushed it to my own github repository.
https://github.com/kidsid59/appExample
When I tried to use it in my own sample project by making an entry in its podfile like

```
target "PodInstallDemoApp" do

pod ‘appExample’, :git => 'https://github.com/kidsid59/appExample.git'

end
```

And then tried to run "pod install" in terminal.
It says :-

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `‘appExample’' for #    <Pod::Podfile:0x007f92e111dfc0>. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
```

Looks like its failing to identify the pod name.
I already wasted lot of time in this little advice would help.

Answer (score 43):

You probably have edited your `Podfile` with TextEdit.app, which replace `'` for "smart quotes" (`‘` and `’`.

Be sure to use regular quotes (`'`).

Comment: i don't understand message clearly

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**: You shouldn’t use TextEdit App to edit the pod file because TextEdit likes
>   to replace standard quotes with more graphically appealing quotes.
>   This can cause CocoaPods to get confused and display errors, so it’s
>   best to just use Xcode or another programming text editor.

Using TextEdit App will give you following,

```
pod ‘AFNetworking’, ‘~> 2.5′    //notice the quotes
```

Use Xcode to open Podfile and you will get correct quotes as following,

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

Terminal Commands to open in Xcode:

```
$ touch Podfile  //OR $ cd <parentDirectory of Podfile>
$ open -a Xcode Podfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you don't have any tag ?

Try to do this:

```
$ git add -A && git commit -m "Release 0.0.1."
$ git tag '0.0.1'
$ git push --tags
```